# Mocking REST Webservice on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, web-services, mocking

What is the best (simplest, easy to install and use) solution to mock a webservice on OSX to test my iPhone-App?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preferred tool for mocking up REST interfaces is [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com). That said, if I were building a new one today, I would probably investigate [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org) (just because I've been growing more interested in Python than Ruby of late; this is not a statement on the relative merits of the languages or the frameworks). If you google a bit for "sinatra alternatives" you'll find several other frameworks in this space. I've had great luck with Sinatra, though.